# Typescript: Returning a union based on ReturnTypes in object

Tags: typescript

My initial code is as follows, it allows me to detect the type of **data** based on the **type** when doing a switch on action:ActionType.

```
enum Actions {
  GET_MESSAGES,
  GET_MESSAGES_LOADED
}

//@ts-ignore
const AppActions = {
  getMessages() {
    return {
      type: Actions.GET_MESSAGES,
      data:{id: 1}
    };
  },
  getMessagesLoaded() {
    return {
      type: Actions.GET_MESSAGES_LOADED,
      data:{messages: ['asdf']}
    };
  }
};

type ActionType = ReturnType<typeof AppActions[keyof typeof AppActions]>;


const func = (action:ActionType) => {
  // @ts-ignore
  switch (action.type) {
      case Actions.GET_MESSAGES:
          console.log(action.data.id) //Should pass
          break
      case Actions.GET_MESSAGES_LOADED:
        console.log(action.data.messages) //Should pass
          break;
      case Actions.GET_MESSAGES_ERROR: // Should throw typescript error
      // default:
      //   break;
  }
};
```

What I'd like to know is can I create the ActionType union dynamically by mapping over keys of AppActions?

**Closest Answer so far**

@Elias's answer so far of `type ActionType = ReturnType<typeof AppActions[keyof typeof AppActions]>;` cuts out most of the bloat here.

The above works perfectly so long as each function in AppActions has a specified return type, without this the type of data cannot be detected however it does detect correctly Actions.GET_MESSAGES_ERROR is an invalid action.type.

Comment: Does `type ReturnTypeOfKeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? ReturnType<typeof AppActions[T]> : never;` solve this for you?

Comment: @RazLuvaton How does this work? If you look at my solution, it's really easy to understand in comparison to this. Not saying yours is not good, I'm genuinely interested.

Comment: @Elias That solution works with the fact that conditional types over generic unions become distributive: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types

Comment: I’m loving your respectful comment!

Comment: Looks like this is above my head... @IngoBürk but thanks for the doc link!

Comment: @RazLuvaton I'm unsure as to why, but it is reporting an error for me :( https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-c7emdb?file=index.ts

Comment: Try this instead - `type ReturnTypeOfKeysOfUnion<T> = T extends keyof typeof AppActions ? ReturnType<typeof AppActions[T]> : never;`

Comment: The first type I wrote I haven’t tested (I wrote it on my phone )

Comment: @RazLuvaton How would one initialize it? `let m: ReturnTypeOfKeysOfUnion = AppActions.getMessagesLoaded();`  will not work because of the missing type argument. This is especially important as my answer seems to be invalid. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68703207/typescript-returning-a-union-based-on-returntypes-in-object/68703333#comment121416793_68703333

Comment: I see it’s not working, I’m out of ideas ‍♂️

Comment: @RazLuvaton Honestly this is my "answer by heart", but not really the answer to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68703207/typescript-returning-a-union-based-on-returntypes-in-object/68703333#comment121416940_68703333

Answer (score 1):

This answer works in extracting the type, but type guards fail to resolve and reveal the underlying type!

[image]

[image]

## Anser

```js
type ActionType = ReturnType<typeof AppActions[keyof typeof AppActions]>;
```

You don't even need to specify the return type of the functions:

```js
const AppActions = {
    getMessages() {
        return {
            messages: ["asdf"],
        };
    },
    getMessagesLoaded() {
        return {
            loadedMessages: [1],
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: Hmm this seems so close, maybe it's my IDE but this doesn't seem to detect the data type. 

I've adjusted my question to make it a bit simpler.

Comment: Huh, you are right! I assume because typescript cannot determine the underlying type in the switch, it still is of type `ActionType` even after the type guard. I'm afraid I cannot help you here :(

Comment: It's worth noting however if the return type is explicitly defined per function this does work perfectly.

Comment: @KyleJohnson I know it might seem easier to write code when it is dynamic, but I think it is better if you have a separate response interface for every action. That way you can write functions that only accept certain responses without having to type guard them.

Comment: Perhaps you're right, I do have a cli that writes all this code so it wouldn't be a big deal. Your ActionType solution gets rid of the majority of bloat anyway!

Comment: @KyleJohnson I'm sorry that I could not be of further assistance

Comment: @KyleJohnson Perhaps someone more skilled than I can tell if this is actually a typescript bug? I would imagine it should resolve to `{loadedMessages: ...`

Comment: Maybe, it does seem that way you're right! Perhaps it's too expensive to detect this.